# When a ring is a polynomial ring?

Tags: polynomials, ac.commutative-algebra, noncommutative-algebra

In the [paper](http://ac.els-cdn.com/0021869372901342/1-s2.0-0021869372901342-main.pdf?_tid=b2465a4a-0c5f-11e6-a45e-00000aacb35e&acdnat=1461751763_b988e36aab89436b8ec89ff4d763c321) (2.11) the authors show that if $k^*$ is a separable algebraic extension of $k$ and $x_1,x_2, \ldots, x_n$ are indeterminates over $k^*$ and a normal one dimensional ring $A$ with $k \subset A \subset k^*[x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n]$ then $A$ has the form $k'[t]$ where $k'$ is the algebraic closer of $k$ in $A$.

The above is a very strict sufficient condition to ensure the polynomial property. Is there a general answer to the question:

Q. When a ring $R$ is a polynomial ring over a field?

Comment: This is a difficult problem, even when $R$ is a finitely generated subring of a ring of polynomials. You shouldn't expect a definite answer. You might like to have a look at van den Essen's "Seven Lectures on Polynomial Automorphisms" (in id. ed., *Automorphisms of Affine Space* (Curaçao 1994), Springer 1995), or his book *Polynomial Automorphisms and the Jacobian Conjecture* (Birkhäuser 2000).

Comment: In the result you cite, there is a slight generalization.  To deduce the same result for every normal, one-dimensional subring $A$ of a $k$-algebra $B$, it suffices that (i) for the integral closure $k^*$ of $k$ in $B$, the fraction field $k^*(B)$ has vanishing irregularity, i.e., there is no non-constant $k^*$-rational transformation from $\text{Spec}(B)$ to an Abelian variety, and (ii) every invertible element of $B$ is integral over $k$.